# Vertical align element in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling for quite some time now with that.
I have 2 floated div and I'd like to align the text with the images inside these divs.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfAL6/)

```
<div data-role="content" class="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-icon="nf-arrow-r">
            <div style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <img src='http://images.lecouffe.org/wp-content/uploads/Chronometre.png' width='22' height='22' />08h00 - 12h30
                    <br/>
                    <img src='http://images.lecouffe.org/wp-content/uploads/Chronometre.png' width='22' height='22' />13h00 - 18h00</div>
                <div style="float:right;font-weight:normal;color:blue;">9h30 +
                    <img src='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000050266964/cfbc5ac04a7ced31fcbb9dfcf1649d65.png' width='32' height='32' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `vertical-align` property on anything?

Comment: Have you tried using the `vertical-align` CSS property? A value of `middle` should work for you.

Comment: Yes of course I tried that. but no success so far

Comment: so align it vertically? next to the images?

Comment: What do you mean "of course"? You haven't posted anything that uses that nor mentioned what about it doesn't work.

Comment: @peterchon Yes exactly as you can see at the moment there is a small gap

Comment: @j08691 I didn't mean to be rude and I wrote that. But you're right I should've wrote what I tried so far. Apologies!

Comment: Is there any way you could post an image of how you want it positioned? I'm not sure which gap you are referring to.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/HfAL6/2/). I have added `vertical-align` and wrapped the text in a `span`.

Comment: @Harry Seems OK to me. So it was the span the issue here. Thanks a lot . Post you response as an answer, this way I can validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue by

1. Wrapping the text content inside a `<span>` tag.
2. And then by adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to your `<span>` and `<img>` tags.

**HTML:**

```
<img src='http://images.lecouffe.org/wp-content/uploads/Chronometre.png' width='22' height='22' /><span>08h00 - 12h30</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
img, span{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[**Working Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/HfAL6/2/)

**Note:** The working sample has `border` just to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be using `table` and `table-cell` displays. I've colored the cells so it'll be clear.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/HfAL6/5/)

I had to change some styles, **but not the DOM**.

```
<div style="font-weight:normal;color:blue;background:red;
            vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;
            height:100%; text-align:right;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in all image tags.

```
style='vertical-align:middle;'
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/HfAL6/4/)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but the text is not really align with the images

Comment: It's aligned correctly, just you image not in right size. see the burger image.